# when trying to call a local component function (ping_device ) from click event of chart then it show's "this.ping_device is not a function"

Tags: angular

i am try to call a funtion when svgrenderer button is clicked

this the error

[image: 1]

this is my event of chart in which i am creating a button using svgrenderer

```js
events: {
    click: function(event) {
        debugger
        console.log(event);
        var point = this,
            chart = this.chart;

        if (chart.customTooltip) { // destroy the old one when rendering new
            chart.customTooltip.destroy();
            chart.customTooltip = undefined;
        }
        chart.customTooltip = chart.renderer.button(
            'Ping',
            chart.plotLeft + event.point.plotX,
            chart.plotTop + event.point.plotY - 80,
            function() {
                debugger
                this.ping_device(event.point.id.trim());
            }
        ).attr({ // style tooltip
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 8,
            stroke: 'red',
            padding: 8,
            r: 3,
            fill: 'rgb(247, 247, 247)'
        }).add();
        chart.rGroup.translate(-chart.customTooltip.width / 2, -chart.customTooltip.height + 40).toFront() // translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
}

ping_device(device) {
    `enter code here`
    console.log(device);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the reference of `this` into a variable and use the reference name to invoke `ping_device` method. Below is the refined code.

```js
/***** Store reference of this keyword into _this variable *****/
var _this = this;

...

{
    click: function(event) {
        debugger console.log(event);
        var point = this,
            chart = this.chart;
        if (chart.customTooltip) { // destroy the old one when rendering new
            chart.customTooltip.destroy();
            chart.customTooltip = undefined;
        }
        chart.customTooltip = chart.renderer.button(
            'Ping',
            chart.plotLeft + event.point.plotX,
            chart.plotTop + event.point.plotY - 80,
            /***** Use _this reference name instead of this keyword *****/
            function() {
                debugger
                _this.ping_device(event.point.id.trim());
            }
        ).attr({ // style tooltip
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 8,
            stroke: 'red',
            padding: 8,
            r: 3,
            fill: 'rgb(247, 247, 247)'
        }).add();
        chart.rGroup.translate(-chart.customTooltip.width / 2, -chart.customTooltip.height + 40).toFront() // translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
}
```

Comment: now i am getting mentioned error "error TS2339: Property 'chart' does not exist on type 'NetworkChartComponent'.         206             chart = this.chart;"

Comment: @yashwardhan, I have updated the code in answer. Please check it out.